# Table doesn't show in list of tables in SSMS query designer GUI after table creation script

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

If I create a table with a script in SQL Server Management Studio, then the table won't show up in the list of available tables when using the Query Designer (right-click "Design in Query Editor" or Ctrl+Shift+Q when in a query worksheet).

It shows up in the list of tables in the correct database after refreshing. I have tried both refreshing the table list, refreshing the intellisense from the context menu and keyboard shortcut, and even connecting and reconnecting.

The only thing that fixes it is completely restarting SSMS.

Is there a way to get the new table to show up  without restarting or reconnecting?

I am using SSMS 2012, but I assume it applies to other versions as well.

Comment: At the risk of sounding really snippy, you should learn to write your queries without using the wizard. Once you get comfortable with it you will find that it is way faster than grabbing a mouse and pointing everywhere.

Comment: I can, I have an MCSE in SQL Server, but when you have to join two tables with a key across 6-10 columns (vendor designed, not mine), it's much faster to do it with the query designer and drag and drop.There is this and other instances where the query designer is faster than typing.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the database name then select new query will change the query file name to servername.DBname 
it helps to open tables in query designer table